# DELETE query with Common Table Expression ("WITH AS " clause)

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression, sql-delete

I am trying to delete 41,6% of my old rows from my oracle data table ( senstrig is a date format):

```
DELETE FROM
    (WITH RS AS (SELECT * FROM OLD_WIFISIGN WHERE SENSID= 1 ORDER BY SENSTRIG ASC))
WHERE ROWNUM <= (SELECT COUNT (*)/ 2.4 FROM RS);
```

But it returns an error:

> ORA-00928 missing SELECT

I have already tried several versions but with no luck.

Could you please help me how can I make this "delete from" runnable?

Comment: I'd put WITH before DELETE. I.e. something like WITH RS ... DELETE FROM RS WHERE ...

Comment: To help you find information, that `WITH AS` syntax is called a "Common Table Expression" or "CTE"; I've edited the question to include that keyword.

Comment: @jarlh That sounds like an answer, not a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test table, 1000 rows, all with `sensid = 1`:

```
create table old_wifisign (sensid, senstrig) as (
  select 1, trunc(sysdate) - level 
    from dual connect by level <= 1000);
```

Delete:

```
delete 
  from old_wifisign  
  where rowid in (
      select rowid 
        from (
          select rowid, row_number() over (order by senstrig) / count(1) over () rto 
            from old_wifisign 
            where sensid = 1 )
        where rto <= .416)
```

Result: 416 rows with oldest senstrig deleted. Note that only sensid 1 is taken into calculations here, as in your query.

Answer (score 1):

To  delete 41,6% of old rows check fist the boundary date to delete and than use it.

The analytic function [`PERCENT_RANK`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm#i1043951) gives you the youngest `senstrig` you do not want to delete.

```
with perc_rank as (
select SENSID, SENSTRIG,
PERCENT_RANK()  OVER (ORDER BY senstrig) AS pr
from old_wifisign)
select max(SENSTRIG) from perc_rank 
where pr < .416
```

Than you simple takes this date and performs a `DELETE`

```
delete from old_wifisign
where SENSTRIG < 
(with perc_rank as (
  select SENSID, SENSTRIG,
  PERCENT_RANK()  OVER (ORDER BY senstrig) AS pr
  from old_wifisign) 
select max(SENSTRIG) from perc_rank 
where pr < .416
);
```

Anyway you should take soem care considering *ties* - thing about a case when half of the rows in the table have identical `senstrig`

Comment: You are welcome @AkosVincze and with this approach you'll be much better that the accepted answer on large tables, as you save the `NESTED LOOPS` and row by row delete on nearly 1/2 of the table - only one `FULL TABLE SCAN` will be done.